# Could paperclip handle non-image files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using Ruby on Rails 2.3.5

I want to let the user upload files, not only images, but also music files or just txt documents.

Could I use paperclip for this purpose (I will store those files in Amazon S3)? Is there any special things I have to note about?

Or if the paperclip gem could not handle them, what could I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paperclip does all you asked. I also used to upload mp3 files with paperclip to rackspace cloud. Never had any sort of problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How's the thumbnail function? Could I assign a thumbnail to it or it just useless in this case?